# Qu’est-ce que « d’où » veut dire?

Tags: traduction

J'ai entendu dire « D’où tu me parles comme ça? » et « D’où tu me mattes? » et selon la traduction « from where » ces deux phrases n’ont aucun sens en anglais (surtout la deuxième). Je peux comprendre si la première vient de « from where did you learn to talk to me like that? » mais la deuxième je peux seulement la traduire par « Why are you looking at me? » selon le context (c'était une confrontation).

Il y a une meilleure traduction qui peut être utilisé sur ces deux situations parce qu'ils me semblent être très similaire? Ou est-ce que j'ai mal compris la conversation?

Comment: Je voulais clarifier que ces deux phrases ne viennent pas d’une conversation mais de deux qui n’ont aucun rapport avec l’autre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tout depend du contexte, mais *D’où* peut-être traduite à *par quelle autorité* ou bien *qui t'as permis* et les remplacer dans vos phrases donnera un sens admissible selon le contexte.

Comment: J'utiliserais plutôt légitimité qu'autorité, mais à ceci près, je partage l'opinion émise par cette réponse.
Il fut un temps où la jeunesse étudiante politisée employait "D'où est-ce que tu parles, camarade?". J'imagine que le "d'où", dans cette question, fait référence à l'origine sociale, et questionne quant à la légitimité du locuteur à émettre une certaine opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Déjà c'est simple il faut d'abord bien comprendre les différentes signification de "Où" et les différents sens.

I) où , adverbe

Sens 1: L'endroit où.
Exemple : Il n'a pas à me dire où je dois aller.
Traduction anglais : where

Sens 2: Le moment où.
Synonyme : quand
Traduction anglais : when

Sens 3: Marque la conséquence.
Exemple : D'où ma surprise quand j'ai appris la nouvelle.

II)  où , pronom

Sens 1: Désigne un lieu indiqué précédemment.
Exemple : Le pays où il est né.
Traduction anglais : where

Sens 2: Désigne une situation.
Exemple : Dans l'état où il est, il ne peut pas faire grand-chose.

Sens 3: Désigne un temps.
Exemple : Au moment où il est sorti.
Traduction anglais : that

Voici les différents emplois du où avec accent, j'espère que ma contribution vous aidera.

III) "d'où " est un adverbe interrogatif invariable

Sens1( sens propre):  signifie "de quel endroit"
Exemple: -savez-vous d'où elle arrive?
-d'où venez-vous?

Sens2( figuré) signifie "de quoi" marquant l'origine où la cause.
Exemple: - d'où lui vient cette orgueil?
- voilà d'où cet usage tire son origine.